# Details of tapped MKMapView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, mkmapview

In my ios app, each cell in `TableView` has a MapView on it(each with separate points). When a user clicks on the `MKMapView`, the app should go to another `UIViewcontroller`, displaying the `MKMapView` in full screen and if it occurred somewhere else in the cell, it should go to a "details" page. But I cannot get the program to recognise, if the tap that has occurred within the frame of the `MapView` or not. I tried `-touchesBegan`, but the control doesn't even reach the method.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You Can create custom UIView and add mapView as subview of it and set userInteractionEnabled to NO. Now you can use a UIGestureRecognizer to detect touches.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *sigleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
sigleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
sigleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[yourCustomView addGestureRecognizer:sigleTap];


- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
   your next logic
}
```

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer in UITableView, may add some shadow behaviour with cell's touches. For example: http://goo.gl/oXoFzD.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the mapView to other UIControl instance and disable taps on the map view  (mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO). And add target/action to the control. (But you should make something to determine what control was touched, for example you can use tag property of the control to set index of the model).